# Curtain is making weird moves

Tags: cycles-render-engine, cloth-simulation

I am doing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4G9cMi8QAa4) tutorial and somehow I have managed to have my curtain behave very strange. I must have made an error somewhere but I don't know where. I have attached my file.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloth simulations like those usually take a few frames to settle.

It is normal that the first few frames go weird on you: the simulation calculates how the mesh behaves with gravity, and how the pinning affects its shape, based on in its physical characteristics. If there are no more forces acting on it, the movement will eventually stop.

You can set the cache to start before your scene (like 200 frames) so that by the time the scene starts the curtain has already settled on it's resting postition.

Other way to have the same result, is just to make your scene start at a later frame, so that the movement is not part of the frames to be rendered.

[image]

And one more thing you can fix in the cache section: if your animation is 6000 frames, set the **End** value of the cache to that frame. Otherwise your simulation will stop at the default frame (which is 250).

Comment: hi, I am not sure why my animation is 6000 frames. I suspect this is because I installed some AddOns and later deleted them but some things have remained in the system. I did have a look at User Preferences but I cannot find a way to reset the number of frames.

Comment: But If I let run the animation I don't see things change, I still only see the weird behaviour at the start of the animation or should I bake first ?? In the tutorial at 25:30 min the curtain immediate starts moving ? By the way, I now have linked the tutorial in my question

Comment: @OldMan everytime you make changes to a simulation your cache and bake become invalid, as they will not reflect the change. Prees the free all bakes option and re-cache (or bake). Only then you'll see the changes.

Comment: Thanks. It was some time ago that I worked kWh Physics in Blender. It seemed that Blender Guru just played the simulation (without baking) and that is why I thought I had made an error. I did ... I had not baked before I played the simulation.